# Stationary mouse causing abrupt up and down movements

Tags: windows-10, mouse, scrolling

I have a wired mouse that has some issues with scrolling. My biggest issue is that sometimes it keeps scrolling up and down randomly and abruptly even when I am not touching the mouse.

The mouse stays in the exact same position with no button being pressed. However, the page still keeps scrolling up and down randomly.

It doesn't happen constantly but seems to happen randomly. What could be causing this issue?

1. I have tried different ports.
2. I have cleaned the mouse after opening it.
3. Uninstalled and installed the device driver.

What else should I be doing? The problem is that this keeps happening to all my mice after about 15 months and I am tired of purchasing new ones.

Is 15 months the average lifetime of a mouse?

I have Windows 10 and a wired Lenovo mouse.

Thanks.

Comment: I presume it is an optical mouse? Try a different surface. Yours might be reflective in a certain way that is interfering with the optics.

Comment: Can be anything including hardware issue. Try different mouse.

Comment: An optical mouse has a virtually unlimited life. Currently using a Kensington wired mouse more than 12 years old. It does need occasional cleaning, and the silicone rubber covering the wheel needed replacement (a piece of bicycle inner-tube woks well).